# d3v4 pie chart - on segment hover - expand the segment like a cake slice

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am adjusting this pie chart code - and trying to animate the segment so it juts out like a piece of cake on hover. Not sure why the scope of the mouseover/leave events are not working. I've tried to adjust the radius but its as if its not getting the arc object properly

http://jsfiddle.net/xejmwnob/

```
var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var data = [{"label":"Category A", "value":20}, 
                  {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
                  {"label":"Category C", "value":30},
           {"label":"Category A", "value":20}, 
                  {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
                  {"label":"Category C", "value":30},
           {"label":"Category A", "value":20}, 
                  {"label":"Category B", "value":50}, 
                  {"label":"Category C", "value":5}];


var $this = '#chart';

        d3.select($this)
            .selectAll('svg')
            .remove();

        

        const width = 300,
            height = 300,
            radius = 120,
            innerradius = 0;

        
        var arc = d3
            .arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(innerradius);

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.total = +d.value;
        });

        var pie = d3
            .pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {
                return d.total;
            });

        var svg = d3
            .select($this)
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'piechart')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments');

        var slices = segments
            .selectAll('.arc')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc');

        slices
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .transition()
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.1, d.endAngle);
                return function(t) {
                    d.endAngle = i(t);
                    return arc(d);
                }
            });

          slices.on('mouseover', function(d) {                            
            console.log("mouseover", radius); 

            console.log("this", this)
            console.log("d3.select(this)", d3.select(this))


                let expandArc = d3.arc()
                            .innerRadius(innerradius)
                            .outerRadius(radius * 1.2);

                /*
                d3
                    .arc()
                    .outerRadius(radius)
                    .innerRadius(innerradius)
                */   

                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    //.ease('bounce')
                    .attr('d', expandArc);



          });                                                           

          slices.on('mouseout', function() {                              
            console.log("mouseout");                          
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly by "pull the slice out", then you want to translate the position of the slice, not change its shape.

The hard part is figuring out where to translate the shape to so that the slice moves from the center along the correct angle. The simplest solution is to use the [centroid](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arc_centroid), the midpoint of the slice and then adjust those values as necessary:

```
slices.on('mouseover', function(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (arc.centroid(d)[0] / 2) + ',' + (arc.centroid(d)[1] / 2) + ')');
});

slices.on('mouseout', function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
});
```

Here I divide the centroid x and y values in half so the slices don't go off the SVG area.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pcclarke/av2g195k/2)

PS: `var color = d3.scale.category20c();` is d3v3, to do it in d3v4 it would be: `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);`. The Fiddle you linked is using both.

Comment: this is great -- how do you pull it out only a little - (arc.centroid(d)[0] / 2)  -- why divide by 2?

Comment: I see - without the /2 - it juts out towards half the segment

Answer (score 2):

#### Expand the slice

The mouse event is bind with `slices`, the `<g>` element actually.
Then `d3.select(this)` is the `<g>` instead of the exact `path` element. You can see `<g>` will have `d` attribute after hover, but we need to change the `d` of the `path`.

Try

```
slices.on('mouseover', function(d) {          
    let expandArc = d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerradius)
                .outerRadius(radius * 1.2);   

    d3.select(this)
        .select("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        //.ease('bounce')
        .attr('d', expandArc);
});
```

#### Translate the slice

Locate the centroid of the path and translate it when hovered

```
let offset = 4;// how much do you want to translate from the origin
slices.on('mouseover', function(d) {                            
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + arc.centroid(d)[0] / offset + ',' + arc.centroid(d)[1] / offset + ')')

});                                                           

slices.on('mouseout', function() {                                     
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')                     
});
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5f0jqknm/5/)

Comment: I see -- how do you pull the slice out - more like a cake slice - so its pulled from the center

Comment: Then we should change the `translate` of the slice instead of changing the radius. Updated answer